# Changing the ImageStream cluster wide scheduled refresh interval

Tags: openshift, imagestream

I am using the Openshift resource ImageStream to to pull latest images from our external image repository for our test environments so when a new image is built for an application it gets rolled out automatically when ImageStream identifies a new image available.

```
importPolicy:
  scheduled: true
```

Currently it seems to have a cluster wide refresh interval of 15 minutes according to
[Openshift 4.13 docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/openshift_images/image-streams-manage.html#images-imagestream-import_image-streams-managing)

> This command causes OpenShift Container Platform to periodically update this particular image stream tag. This period is a cluster-wide setting set to 15 minutes by default.

How can i reduce this interval to for example 5 minutes?

Is there any performance issue reducing this refreshing interval?

Openshift version: 4.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change this default value in OpenShift 4.x so far.
So, if you need to re-import your image more frequently, you could manually re-import the image with a CronJob or a script you implement.